# Python DataFrame replace not recognizing strings

Tags: python, csv, pandas, replace

I have imported a csv file as a DataFrame. It has two columns, with the first line being the column name:

```
To Group        Group To
 A Name          A Group
 ...             ....
```

Later I have to make a new column called "Grouping" in which it is basically the "Name" column but with some names replaced with the following method.

```
filtered["Grouping"] = filtered["Name"].replace(list(self.map_group["To Group"]), list(self.map_group["Group To"]))
```

This method seems to work very well, except for two of my rows. Those row's "Grouping" column is the same as their "Name". I have tried replacing my "name" strings in the csv files, using notepad and Excel to no use. I have also printed

```
print("a name" in list(self.map_group["To Group"]))
```

And that equals true. It doesn't seem like I have made a spelling mistake. I have also added regex = True to the method with no changes as well.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear to me what the `Name` column is. Is it the same as the `To Group` column?

Comment: Poorly framed question. Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Thanks will take note